# get ErrorLine Number in SSJS XPages

Tags: error-handling, xpages

how to get errorline number in this try catch() If an error accures.

```
try 
{
  //IF an error happens here show me the errorLine Number?
}
catch(e)
{
    print(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XPages OpenLog Logger automatically handles that for you, as well as catching any uncaught exceptions. I would strongly recommend using it, which is why it is also automatically included in OpenNTF Domino API. Both are Apache licensed, so there are no prohibitions to them being included in commercial code.

If you want to code that yourself, the code is open sourced. I won't include the lines here, because it is extensive. You need to identify the Java class of the SSJS exception returned and then call the relevant method in each. It took a large amount of trial and error to identify the potential Java classes relating to all SSJS exceptions. I can't guarantee I have identified them all (another reason I would recommend using XPages OpenLog Logger instead), but I have not had any defects logged for additional Java classes in the last year.

Comment: I have been using OpenLog. I just want to create a simple error raise by my own then i would like to learn how i can manage that. 
Thank you .

Comment: Unfortunately, because SSJS just receives error objects, as you can see from the method I use (over 100 lines long!), unless you exclude certain class types, it's far from simple https://stash.openntf.org/projects/OPENLOG/repos/xpages-openlog-logger/browse/OpenLogJava/WebContent/WEB-INF/src/com/paulwithers/openLog/OpenLogPhaseListener.java#171. For some it's a case of navigating up through causes of the exception, and for some it's not possible to get the line number.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a shame this openlogger is not included in the domino product. If you have no possibility to change the server configuration there is no way to use it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, unfortunately. It would be better as a comment on the other answer instead.